# How to convert pandas.DataFrame to datatable.Frame containing Int32 (nullable integer)?

Tags: python, pandas, py-datatable

I have a [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) containing [pandas nullable integer data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) and want to convert it to an equivalent [`datatable.Frame`](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/frame.html) object. However it seems it is not directly possible. What is the best way of doing the conversion without breaking stuff? I do not have the DataFrames available in text form, but they com e from a `pickle`. MWE:

```py
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, datatable as dt
vec = [0,1,2, np.nan]
df = pd.DataFrame(vec, dtype="Int32")
frame = dt.Frame(vec, stypes=["int32"])   # works fine
dt.Frame(df)   # raises error
# TypeError: Cannot create a column from <class 'pandas.core.arrays.integer.IntegerArray'>
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but consider another alias for `datatable`, since `dt` is very commonly used as alias for the `datetime` package

Comment: @oskros the `datatable`  documentation uses `dt` as the default, so I think it makes sense to stick to that in the context of this question.

Comment: I think you should raise it as an issue on [github](https://github.com/h2oai/datatable/issues), so that the maintainers can work on it. At the moment, it does look like ``datatable`` is not recognizing pandas nullable integer data type

Comment: FR: https://github.com/h2oai/datatable/issues/2761

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way I found was... first converting to numpy and then to Datatable (and then just add the column names), to me it preserved the data format:

```
import datatable as dt
import pandas as pd

x = pandas_dataframe.to_numpy()
y = dt.Frame(x)

y.stypes #verify the format
```

Hope it helps!